# Implement custom loading message DURANDAL

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, durandal

Hi i've got a durandal app that send data trought ajax but i dont know how to implement the loading indicator , here is the codes:

this is the view that loads the data
loadinbox.html

```
<div class="modal-content messageBox">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3>LOGIN</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
       <h3>Entre com suas credenciais.</h3>
       <form data-bind="submit: ok">
           <input type="text" data-bind="value: login" placeholder="CPF"  class="form-control autofocus" />
           <input type="text" data-bind="value: senha" placeholder="Senha" class="form-control autofocus" />
       </form>
    </div>
    <div data-bind="if: $parent.loading">
        <img src="img/loading.gif"/>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-success" data-bind="click: ok, active: $parent.loading">Login</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is the model that loads the data
loginBox.js

```
define(function (require) {
    var dialog = require('plugins/dialog');


    var loading = ko.observable();

    var loginBox = function(){
        this.login = '';
        this.senha = '';
        this.loading = false;
    };


 loginBox.prototype.ok = function () {
     this.loading =true;

     $.ajax({
         type: "post", 
         data: { "LoginForm[cpf]" : this.login, "LoginForm[password]" : this.senha , 'ajax':'login-form' },
         url: localStorage['baseurl']+localStorage['router']+'site/login',
         success: function (data){
             console.log(data);
         },
         error: function (request, status, error){
             console.log(request.status);
             console.log(status);
             console.log(error);
         },
         complete: function (data) {
             alert('hqweuiqhioehqio');
             this.loading =false; 
         }
     });
 };


 loginBox.show = function() {
     return dialog.show(new loginBox());
 };    

 return loginBox;

});
```

Answer (score 1):

On the surface, your approach is sound, but your approach to modules in Durandal is a little muddled.  For example, you've declared `loading` twice, once as a scalar and once as an observable.

So, let's create an instance module (which means that we're going to return a constructor function):

**loginBox.html** (view)

```
<div class="modal-content messageBox">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3>LOGIN</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <h3>Entre com suas credenciais.</h3>
        <form data-bind="submit: ok">
           <input type="text" data-bind="value: login" placeholder="CPF"  class="form-control autofocus" />
           <input type="text" data-bind="value: senha" placeholder="Senha" class="form-control autofocus" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <div data-bind="if: $parent.loading()">
        <img src="img/loading.gif"/>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-success" data-bind="click: ok, active: $parent.loading()">
            Login
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice that I changed your `if` binding to this:

```
"if: loading()"
```

referencing `loading` with parentheses.  This performs an immediate eval using the default value supplied to the observable, and then a re-eval when the observable changes.

Also, it may be necessary to change `"click: ok, active: $parent.loading()"` to `click: $parent.ok.bind($parent), active: $parent.loading()`.  Check your context using the debugger when the #ok function is entered.

A note on logic: It seems to me that what you might mean in the modal footer is

```
active: !$parent.loading()
```

Should the OK button really be active when the form is loading data?

**loginBox.js (module instance approach)**

```
define (
    [
        'plugins/dialog',
        'knockout'
    ],
    function (
        dialog,
        ko) {

        var LoginBox = function () {

            this.login = '';
            this.senha = '';
            this.loading = ko.observable(false);
        };

        LoginBox.prototype.ok = function () {
            var _vm = this;

            this.loading(true);

            $.ajax( {
                type: "post", 
                data: { "LoginForm[cpf]" : this.login, "LoginForm[password]" : this.senha , 'ajax':'login-form' },
                url: localStorage['baseurl']+localStorage['router']+'site/login',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {
                    console.log(request.status);
                    console.log(status);
                    console.log(error);
                },
                complete: function (data) {
                    alert('hqweuiqhioehqio');
                    _vm.loading(false);
                }
           });
        };

        LoginBox.prototype.show = function() {
            dialog.show(this);
        };  

        return LoginBox;

    };
);
```

Take note of my treatment of `this.loading`.  It is an observable, and observables are updated using the approach I show above (remember, they are *functions*).  When you assign `true` in this manner--`this.loading = true`--you override the observable itself and turn it into a non-observable scalar.  So, when the value later changes (from false to true to false), the view is not updated.

Also note that you must import KnockoutJS.

Another issue: you have a `this` reference issue in your #complete function.  Note that I do this at the top of your #Ok function:

```
var _vm = this;  //Some people are inclined to this format: var that = this;
```

and, then, in your #complete function, I do this:

```
_vm.loading(false);
```

Using `this` in your #complete function references the #complete function itself, not the viewModel.  We have to save a reference to `this` *outside* the #complete function.

There was another problem: #show was not on the prototype.

Comment: when i oppen now it shows the loading image as soon as it oppens the  dialog.

Comment: @talles_jp Please post your entire view (HTML) and viewModel (js).  What you're saying tells me that you are somehow initializing the `loading` observable to true, or that you haven't adjusted your view to dereference the `loading` observable.  I need more information.

Answer (score 0):

I use a utility called [Block UI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/)
in my App JS file I call it like this using the Global Ajax setup. 
By doing it this way you only do it once and then every Ajax call will show your loading gif and hide when any Ajax calls starts and finishes

**HTML:** 
in the index.html page(your main page)

```
  <div id="throbber" style="display:none;">
            <img src="/images/gears.gif" />
        </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
        $.blockUI.defaults.css.border = 'none';
        $.blockUI.defaults.css.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
        $.blockUI.defaults.message = $('#throbber');
        $.blockUI.defaults.showOverlay = true;
        $.blockUI.defaults.overlayCSS.backgroundColor = "#fff";

        $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
                $.blockUI();            
        }).ajaxStop(function () {
            $.unblockUI();
        });
    });
```

**CSS:**

```
#throbber{
    border:1px solid #346789;
    padding: 15px;
    background-Color: #fff;
    -moz-border-radius:0.5em;
    border-radius:0.7em;
    opacity:0.8;
    filter:alpha(opacity=80);
    color: #000 ;
    width:133px;
    height:133px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 40%;
    position: fixed;
 }
```

Comment: I used to use Block UI as well.  It's a good little micro-framework.  But if you look at the OP's question, you'll see that he's using Durandal.  We don't code directly against `$(document).ready()` in Durandal.  Your code would actually be best in the `attached` handler of the **shell.js** viewModel.  Are you actually doing this Durandal?